# Add data to the RoutingContext of Vert.x middleware

Tags: vert.x

Say I have this middleware class:

```
public class Middleware implements Handler<RoutingContext> {
  public void handle(RoutingContext ctx) {
      ctx.set("foo", "bar");  // ctx.set is an imaginary method
      ctx.next();
  }
}
```

the ctx.set() method is made-up - it doesn't exist on version 3.6.2.
So how can we set arbitrary info on the context of the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `put` method for that:

```
public class Middleware implements Handler<RoutingContext> {
  public void handle(RoutingContext ctx) {
      ctx.put("foo", "bar");
      ctx.next();
  }
}
```

Comment: haha damn, thanks, I guessed it would be a method called set, not put, I figure you're right, will accept it tomorrow if it works

Comment: haha, ywc :), it is a put because there is a Map behind the scenes which holds the data.